# How do I call another controller from my view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Hey guys so my problem is I keep getting the Error Page not found 404 when I look in dbo.Log table (My sql database)

Im trying to render a view via a button push from another view, the first view works fine
this is my button from my first view

```html
    <div class="content2">
        <input type="button"
               value="Go to Edit"
               onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "CheckoutAttributes", 200)'" />
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I know the 200 is wrong, I was trying around to call the controller, but even without the 200 it doesnt work

This is my 2 actions in controller thats supposed to render the new view:

```cs
        //[AuthorizeAdmin]
        //[Area(AreaNames.Admin)]
        //trying something, adding areas (end) didnt work
        [HttpGet("/[area]/[controller]/[action]/{orderId:int}")]
        public IActionResult Edit(int orderId)
        {
            Order? order = _orderService.GetOrderById(orderId);

            if (order == null)
            {
                return NotFound(orderId);
            }

            if (order.OrderStatus != OrderStatus.Complete)
            {
                return CannotEdit(orderId, $"{nameof(order.OrderStatus)} is '{order.OrderStatus}', but '{OrderStatus.Complete}' is required.");
            }

            if (order.PaymentStatus != PaymentStatus.Paid)
            {
                return CannotEdit(orderId, $"{nameof(order.PaymentStatus)} is '{order.PaymentStatus}', but '{PaymentStatus.Paid}' is required.");
            }

            if (order.ShippingStatus != ShippingStatus.Delivered)
            {
                return CannotEdit(orderId, $"{nameof(order.ShippingStatus)} is '{order.ShippingStatus}', but '{ShippingStatus.Delivered}' is required.");
            }

            return Edit(order);
        }

        //[AuthorizeAdmin]
        //[Area(AreaNames.Admin)]
        //trying something, adding areas (end) didnt work
        private IActionResult Edit(Order order)
        {
            var model = new CheckoutAttributesEditModel
            {
                OrderId = order.Id,
            };

            ParseXml(order, model);
            ParseDescription(order, model);

            if (!model.AllPredefinedPurchaseReasons.Any())
            {
                // Should not occur under normal circumstances (only when neither the xml nor the description could be parsed).

                (CheckoutAttribute publishAttribute, CheckoutAttribute predefinedPurchaseReasonAttribute, CheckoutAttribute customPurchaseReasonAttribute) = GetCheckoutAttributes();

                model.AllPredefinedPurchaseReasons = predefinedPurchaseReasonAttribute.CheckoutAttributeValues.ToList();

                model.PublishLabel = GetLocalisedAttributeName(publishAttribute);
                model.PredefinedPurchaseReasonLabel = GetLocalisedAttributeName(predefinedPurchaseReasonAttribute);
                model.CustomPurchaseReasonLabel = GetLocalisedAttributeName(customPurchaseReasonAttribute);
            }

            ParseVCHistory(order.Id, model);

            if (model.SelectedPredefinedPurchaseReason <= 0)
            {
                // Should be very unlikely to happen.
                model.SelectedPredefinedPurchaseReason = model.AllPredefinedPurchaseReasons.First().Id;
            }
            //trying somehing, original was return View(model);
            return View($"{Plugin.RelativeDirectoryPath}/Views/CheckoutAttributes/Edit.cshtml", model);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? Keep getting 404 page not found
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add areas in endpoint

```
 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "areas",
                   pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

And create link:

```
<input type="button"
       value="Go to Edit"
       onclick="location.href='@(Url.Action("Edit",new { controller = "CheckoutAttributes",id="123456" }))'" />
```

//or

```
<input type="button"
       value="Go to Edit"
       onclick="location.href='@(Url.Action("Edit","CheckoutAttributes",new { id="123456" }))'" />
```